# update edited row extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

my problem is very easy for you but i can't afford..
i'm getting data from row and showing in other panel's fields
my goal is to edit this data and show edited data in grid ,please give me some advice, i know that it needs `commit() function` but..

my code :

```
   var selModel = persongrid.getSelectionModel();
  var selectedRecords = selModel.getSelection();

 console.log(selectedRecords[0].data)
 me.activeRecord = selectedRecords;

a=selectedRecords[0].data;
  var user = Ext.create('SFG.model.Person',a    );
 me.getForm().loadRecord(user);
```

but it needs continue, please help me..

Comment: Your grid uses another model? Not 'SFG.model.Person' ?

Answer (score 3):

That should do it:

```
var selection = persongrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(),
    record = selection.length > 0 ? selection[0] : null;

me.getForm().loadRecord(record);
```

and when you are done with all edits call

```
me.getForm().updateRecord();
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/UR7xQ/)**

Note the `updateRecord` does the following

- call [beginEdit()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-beginEdit)
- apply the changes
- call [endEdit()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-endEdit)

where `endEdit` also notifies all stores where this instance is bound to

Answer (score 0):

Dont require this much effort, just you need to set the edited value to records and make an sync of the store.

Pushing grid data to form is

```
editUser: function(grid, record) {
        var view = Ext.widget('useredit');

        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    }
```

Pushing edited data back to store

```
updateUser: function(button) {
    var win    = button.up('window'),
        form   = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();

    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
}
```

Note: getUsersStore() is structure as getStore.

Please go through the below link, which could be useful for ur requirement. This link contain what you require with full code along with explaination.

```
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/application_architecture
```

Thanks.